# Proper verb to use with "test"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, collocation

Assume that somebody has created a test/quiz like [this one](http://www.buzzfeed.com/rdio/quiz-indie-rock-frontman-or-random-guy-in-brookly-6uiu).

Has he *developed* the test? *put it together*? *wrote* it? something else?

What verb would you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, "wrote the test" implies he took the test, not that he developed or otherwise created the test. "Compiled" implies he put the test together from previously existing questions. I'd take "designed" to refer to the test format or typeface or possibly intent, not necessarily the content. "Prepared" implies involvement with content, but not necessarily creation: he might have revised a test from last year. So if you mean that he created a new test specifically for a particular use, then "developed" seems closest.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that tests are *written* or *prepared*.

Answer (score 1):

You have already used one option — *created*. You might also use *compiled*. *Put together* could be used, in the form "he put the test together" rather than "he put together the test".

Answer (score 1):

"*Wrote a test*" sounds like somebody took the test, definitely a U-turn from what you are trying to convey.

Again, "*Put together the test*" doesn't sound very convincing and sounds like the person was just a mediator to the entire process of *arranging* the test/quiz.

You can work with "*Designed the test*" or "*Developed the Test*". I particularly prefer, **design** in the [scenario](http://www.buzzfeed.com/rdio/quiz-indie-rock-frontman-or-random-guy-in-brookly-6uiu) you mention since it ably expresses that the person is responsible for, well, designing the test/quiz.

Comment: I consistently have heard instructors refer to "writing a test", and have *never* heard a student use that phrase.  This is in the US (KY), so perhaps usage differs elsewhere.

Comment: @starwed: M curious, what do the students use when they intend to say that they appeared for the test?

Comment: They would just say that they "took the test".

Answer (score 1):

Of the choices you offer, *[developed](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/develop)* is well suited.

> To bring from latency to or toward fulfillment: *an instructor who develops the capabilities of each student.*

A well crafted test is conceived, structured, documented, evaluted, run under controlled conditions, revised, calibrated, standardized, re-evaluated, etc.

If the test you are describing is casually created, a run-it-up-the-flagpole type of measurement, any authoring descriptor would probably do. If it has been carefully put together, if the test has been tested, *developed* captures it.

Answer (score 1):

This website may be helpful to you: http://thesaurus.com/

I would agree that 'created' would be best used, or founded, improved, res-established..

Answer (score 1):

"He composed the test himself" or "created."

I don't have a problem with "He wrote the test" if there is a little more clarification like "itself" or "He wrote the test specifically for his new students."